# 'window.Vue.use is not a function' error on a Vue2 project

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, azure-web-app-service, vuejs3

I have an application running in the Azure web app, it was working well and today the website is down suddenly with an error:

> `window.Vue.use` is not a function

The App uses Vuetify as the frontend.

Does anyone know why? Is there a quick fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Vue.use` is from Vue 2's API, and that's now only available via an [application instance in Vue 3](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/application-api.html#use). The error suggests your app is written with Vue 2's API, while Vue 3 is actually loaded. The timing of the error coincides with the yesterday's update to the `vue` package in NPM.

As of 7-FEB-2022, [version 3 is the default in NPM](https://twitter.com/vuejs/status/1490592213184573441) (i.e., `3.2.30` is now the `latest` version), replacing Vue 2. Your app is likely pulling in `vue` from a CDN, and the URL is missing a version specifier (or you're using `@latest`):

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script> ⛔️ defaults to latest
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest"></script> ⛔️ no longer Vue 2
```

To ensure you're using Vue 2, include the `@2` (or `@2.6.14`) version specifier in the URL:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2"></script>
                                   
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.14"></script>
```